# getting nested data from JSON array object

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**this is what my data looks like**

```
 { _id: 5a114dede58f4a05cb135d96,

   messages: [
        { 
         id: 5a114c66e58f4a05cb135d8c,

         User: 'developer2', 

        _id: 5a114e26e58f4a05cb135d9b,

          texts: [{
                   _id: 5a114e26e58f4a05cb135d9d,
                   message: 'hii',
                   username: 'ruby' 
                  },
                  { 
                   _id: 5a114e40e58f4a05cb135d9e,
                   message: 'es',
                   username: 'shan' 
                  }
                                         ] } ]
                  }
     }
```

**how do I extract all data from texts,**
*I'd used this but this not returning any thing*

```
  <% texts.messages.texts.forEach(function(text){ %>


  <p><%=text.message%></p>
   <p><%=text.username%></p>

   <% })  %>
```

**Edit:when i just printing

<%=texts%>

**

```
{ _id: 5a114dede58f4a05cb135d96,  
    messages: [ { id: 
     5a114c66e58f4a05cb135d8c,
       User: 'developer2', _id: 
     5a114e26e58f4a05cb135d9b,
      texts: [Array] } ] 
}
```

I'm not able to see data inside texts unless I print this

<%=texts.messages%>

*this is what i get  after writing texts.messages *

```
 {
texts: [{
                   _id: 5a114e26e58f4a05cb135d9d,
                   message: 'hii',
                   username: 'ruby' 
                  },
                  { 
                   _id: 5a114e40e58f4a05cb135d9e,
                   message: 'es',
                   username: 'shan' 
                  }
                                         ] } ]
                  }
     }
```

**My route to transfer data to ejs**

```
User.findOne({username:req.user.username},{messages:
      { $elemMatch: { 
      User:req.params.username} }},
      function(err,data){
         if (err) {
            throw err;
           } else {
            res.render("chat",{texts:data,user:founduser});
        }
       })
```

**what am I missing here ?**

Comment: Is the mongod query finding any data, at first place?

Comment: Yes it is , I've checked it is returning whole data

Comment: '<p><%=texts%></p>'prints complete data nested with username only data inside a texts is not printing out

Comment: I've edited it in detail ,now maybe you can tell from where the problem is coming from

Comment: Messages is an array you are using it as an object. If you are certain it is a single entry array then use texts.messages[0].texts.forEach. But it the messages has more that one entry then you have to loop through the messages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% texts.messages.forEach(function(message){
message.texts.forEach(function(text){ %>


<p><%=text.message%></p>
<p><%=text.username%></p>

<% }}))  %>
```